# Creating NSDate from unix timestamp stored in NSNumber on 32/64 bit

Tags: ios, objective-c, 64-bit, nsdate

I have the following code:

```
NSNumber *number = @(1388534400000);

NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[number unsignedIntegerValue]];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];

[self.label setText:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]];
```

It writes `2009. december 4.` on my iPhone 5 and `45970. november 27.` on my iPhone 5s. I suppose the reason is, that on 32 bit architectures the unix timestamps are handled in seconds, but on 64 bit they need to be in milliseconds. How can I detect the architecture? Is dividing by 1000 on 64 bit architectures a good way to solve this problem? Is there some more elegant way to handle this?

Comment: Your code would work if you divide the number by 1000.

Comment: BTW - the correct date for that number is January 1, 2014 UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a 64-bit issue.

`NSTimeInterval` is defined as a `double` so use:

```
NSNumber *number = @(1388534400.000);
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[number doubleValue]];
```

Comment: That isn't the same number that the op wrote.

Comment: @Droppy no it's the number/1000.0 since `NSTimeInterval` is a double with the milliseconds represented in the fractional part.

Comment: The OP's code would work as-is if they simply add `/1000` after the call to `unsignedIntegerValue`.

Comment: Yeah the op didn't make it clear that the number was unix epoch * 1000.